# built in electric double oven

Tags: oven

I live in a condo with 208 voltage, I bought a double wall oven (kitchenAid) it is rated for 240 voltage, this oven does not bake cakes and other baked goods well, they become dried on the outside and not cooked in the middle, do you think this a faulty product or is the problem related to voltage in the condo not being a good match for the ovens?

Comment: get a oven thermometer to check the temp of the oven.  It just sounds like your oven might be running to hot.  A lot of ovens temps are off from what they say and having thermometer in the oven will allow you to adjust the temp up or down to make it where it really needs to be.  Any cooking store or a store that has kitchen gadgets will have a couple you can choose from.  Just remember to take it out before doing any oven cleans (speaking from experience here).

Comment: A miss-set voltage input could throw off the temperature sensor as well.

Comment: Could you get to the model/serial number so that we could reference the specs online?  That would settle the versatility question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be unusual for the oven to only work properly at 240v, as this is not a common household supply voltage in the US and it appears from the Kitchenaid listings on most appliance web sites that they don't SKU up different voltages.  Kitchenaid appears (from a manual I found here: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/287527/Kitchenaid-Architect-Series-Ii-Kerk201.html?page=11) to make at least some of their appliances 208/240 compatible via a menu option to select the type of voltage for more precise control.  The only real change that happens when using 208 vs 240 is a decrease in the design wattage (since the same conductors move fewer watts at 208 vs 240). If you can let us know your model and/or a pic of the oven nameplate (sticker inside the door) that would help us clear up the rest of it.

Its impossible to say if this is affecting your baking abilities but from the description of your problem, does your oven have a convection mode and have you tried turning it off when baking?  Using it will totally throw off recipes that involve delicate substances like batter.

Comment: Jeff Great reference for the oven owner manual. @Heather follow the procedure to change the voltage from 240 to 208. It probably came from the factory set to 240 since that is the prevalent voltage in households in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the oven is working as designed.

It is just not designed to work with the voltage provided.

Until the voltage in the condo equals the voltage required by the oven, the same thing will continue to happen. Crisp burned outside, Raw gooey guts.

To make things really annoying, an oven thermometer will show the oven getting to the right temperature.

If baking temperatures were easy you could bake in 1/2 the time at 2 times the temperature.

Your oven is just too slow to heat up, and too slow to cool down.

Comment: This answer seems dubious to me. Most high-voltage appliances sold in North America are designed to work with either 240v or 208v adequately. The oven's temperature sensor would not be affected by the supply voltage, but it would take longer to heat up. But different heating times are why recipes call for pre-heating, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: And FWIW I have a Kenmore wall oven running on a 208v supply and it works find for baking pies and such. I think the oven is either malfunctioning somehow, was wired incorrectly, or it is user error.